# wso2 API manager publishing runtime to DAS : DAS has no data in WSO2_STATS_DB

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I use independent wso2 API manager 1.10.0 and wso2 DAS 3.0.0 on AWS ec2 to gather statistics of my API usage and I use postgresql to be external RDBMS to store summary data.

***APIM configurations on Admin-Dashboard***

Event Receiver Configurations :

tcp://DAS-IP:7611

Data Analyzer Configurations :

https://DAS-IP:9443

Statistics Summary Datasource :

My-postgresql-url

***APIM configuration in api-manager.xml***

Disable rest client and enable RDBMS client

***DAS configuration***

Set datasource WSO2AM_STATS_DB in master-datasources.xml

***Scenario***

1. Login to APIM publisher
2. Deploy sample API
3. Go to APIM store
4. Subscribe sample API
5. Go to APIM publisher
6. Click statistics > API usage
7. Only show example statistics page.

***APIM Logs***

```
[2016-04-22 06:12:47,787]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 0ms

[2016-04-22 06:12:48,015]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-04-22 06:12:48,015+0000]

[2016-04-22 06:12:48,360]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-04-22 06:12:48,359+0000]

[2016-04-22 06:12:48,605]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-04-22 06:12:48,605+0000]

[2016-04-22 06:12:48,664]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-04-22 06:12:48,664+0000]

[2016-04-22 06:12:48,920]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-04-22 06:12:48,920+0000]

[2016-04-22 06:12:49,296]  INFO - API Initializing API: admin--CalculatorAPI:v1.0

[2016-04-22 06:13:05,384]  INFO - **ReceiverGroup Resending the failed published data...**
```

***DAS Logs***

```
[2016-04-22 04:09:00,218]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected

[2016-04-22 04:09:32,439]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected

[2016-04-22 04:09:47,474]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected

[2016-04-22 04:33:10,239]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected

[2016-04-22 04:35:28,672]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected

[2016-04-22 06:05:18,848]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected

[2016-04-22 06:12:53,017]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected

[2016-04-22 06:13:09,173]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected
```

***DAS WSO2_STATS_DB status***

From DAS dashboard > configure > data sources,I've checked the status of all DB is active and tested connection is healthy.

---

I don't know if WSO2AM_STATS_DB doesn't support postgresql or my configuration gets something wrong.

thanks

Comment: Apparently data has been received by DAS, could you check DAS tables and make sure stats have been persisted?

Comment: `WSO2AM_STATS_DB` supports for postgresql. Have you check the content of that database?

Comment: To Tharik Kanaka and Abmaran Kugathasan:

I check the WSO2-STATS-DB has 8 tables , but no any content there.

API_DESTINATION_SUMMARY
API_FAULT_SUMMARY
API_REQUEST_SUMMARY
API_Resource_USAGE_SUMMARY
API_RESPONSE_SUMMARY
API_VERSION_USAGE_SUMMARY
API_THROTTLED_OUT_SUMMARY
API_LAST_ACCESS_TIME_SUMMARY

Comment: I modified the mysql.sql in APIM_HOME>dbscripts>STAT>sql>mysql.sql to be postgresql.sql , and import successfully.

Comment: I've checked DAS Data exploer, I can see all tables I created for WSO2_STATS_DB, but still no content there.

Comment: How to verify if DAS received events or not??

Comment: I use DAS simulator to send test event and it's successful. I'm curious that if my APIM send wrong event data format to DAS so that the info shows ReceiverGroup Resending the failed published data?

Comment: It's working now, this setting is correct and DAS doesn't accept subscription event so it returns failed published data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a public [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4856) for the APIM Stat scripts folder does not have the PostgreSQL script.

APIM does not publish subscription events to the DAS. Subscription details are kept in the **WSO2AM_DB** database and we used AM_SUBSCRIBER and AM_SUBSCRIPTION table for that purpose.

Hope you followed this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+RDBMS#PublishingAPIRuntimeStatisticsUsingRDBMS-ConfiguringWSO2APIManager).